# Image not displaying on my Xamarin Forms Android emulator

Tags: image, xamarin.forms, display

I have a xamarin forms application. With the following code I try to show an image:

```
var image = new Image { Source = "launcher_foreground.png" };
```

The problem is that it doesn't show the image. The image is included under Sources in the Android specific project. Also, even the icon.png isn't showing, the default image included in the Xamarin forms app. The images are also set to AndroidResource.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

Comment: Is my answer work for you? Don't forget to mark it if it solves your problem:).

Answer (score 1):

1.Please make sure your image has been placed under **Resources/drawable** directory with Build Action: **AndroidResource**.

2.The code you using is right.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var image = new Image { Source = "launcher_foreground.png" };

        Content = image;
    }
```

3.You can't load the `icon.png` as it is not in the **Resources/drawable** directory and the icon is configured in the Android project.

4.High- and low-DPI versions of an image can also be supplied (in appropriately named Resources subdirectories such as drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, and drawable-xhdpi).

There are examples in the document. Also try to clean/rebuild your solution if the image still does not show.

Refer: [local-images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images)

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet , may be help you.

```
var image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromFile("launcher_foreground.png")}
```

Comment: also make sure, set height and width to image view.